# How can I make a command block say a player's name?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I make a Minecraft command block to say somebody's name? I tried doing this:

```
/say You did it @p!
```

Which says in the chat *"You did it @p!"*.

This occurs on both Pocket Edition and on PC. Here's a screenshot showing what happens:

[image: Chat text with selector]

Comment: I don't believe selectors work in `/say` for pocket edition. Might need to wait until they add that.

Comment: This even happens on the computer version on the latest update

Comment: Okay now I know what I did wrong

Comment: There was an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that you put a character directly after the `@p`. So, while:

```
/say You did it @p!
```

wouldn't work,

```
/say You did it @p !
```

does. Inconvenient, as it does include the space in the message, so it would come out as:

> [@] You did it [USERNAME] !

However, I don't know a way around it.

Comment: `/tellraw` might be able to get past this, but I'm no expert at `/tellraw` so don't ask me

Answer (score 1):

You should use `/tellraw`. `/say` is not good for anything. example: `/tellraw @a {"text":"Congrats you did it","color":"blue","extra":[{"selector":"@p"}]}`